# How to have a component selection in inno Setup which extract FreeArc Compressed Archives?

Tags: inno-setup

## Based on Component Selection

Hi, this is my second question, Cause i can't find this one here.

### How to have A Component Selection In Inno Setup Which Extracts files from FreeArc Archives or a Specific Archive?

So here's what i wanna understand, like i created a setup with two options :

Component Type 1 (Default)

Component Type 2

Now here i have a User installing this i want the user to select the both Options or a one.

And one should be default and the second one choose able.
And then when the installation starts the Setup should do the as the user chooses.

**I know this can be easily done with normal inno setup files but i want the setup to extract an *FreeArc* Archive based on Component Type 2.
Only if the user chooses the Scenod Component.**

I know there are many people who have done this before so, Please help me out with this...

***Thanks***

Comment: There are two questions here. One is how to extract the archive. The second is how to extract only when the component is selected. Which one is the question you are asking?

Comment: If the latter, what is your script to extract the archive like?

Comment: 2 Extract only when the component is selected

Comment: OK, so show us your code to extract the archive and we will show you how to make it conditional.

Comment: Sorry i'm on a cyber cafe that's why i'm late

Comment: Okay i guess i can't do that right now cause i'm on cyber cafe

Comment: I mean just a extraction with a FreeArc archive that's all

Comment: I do not understand your last comment *"I mean just a extraction with a FreeArc archive that's all"*. What do you refer to?

Comment: I mean if THE USER selects the second Component the the Inno Wizad should do the install

Comment: That's what we understand. But the solution for that depends on your implementation of the extraction. E.g. if you extract using `[Run]` section entry or Pascal Script or other way.

Comment: No i'm using ISDone.dll with others, so i think you know what i'm talking about.. Well any way i gotta go now thanks for the assist bro, I'll be back Tomorrow..

Comment: I do not know what the `ISDone.dll` is and how that relates to your problem.

Comment: Sorry @Martin i didn't had money to come to a cyber cafe so i couldn't Finish this.. And yeah ISDone is a Plugin for inno setup which helps it to extract various Format based Archives.

Comment: So, show us your code that uses `ISDone.dll` to extract the files.